# How to change coordinates based on window movement?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener

My Code is rather long but it's not the whole thing I'm worried about.
This is in Java.

The class with the issue is located here: http://pastebin.com/5G6QLLBf

The entire code can be posted or e-mailed if needed.

When I run the program, my current method of checking mouse location relative to JPanels in a 2D array I have set up on click is with a function of:

`(Evt.getLocationOnScreen().x - (Correction from the distance of panels to edge of JFrame)  - evt.GetX() - (The Distance between panels))/(The width of the panels)`

with it being the same for y (with a few different numbers) to get 2 integer values equal to that JPanel's position in the array.

However, when the window/JFrame is moved via dragging the top bar, it fails to properly find the panel because one of the constants fails to be correct. How do I correct for window movement? or at least get a value for the amount of window shift?

Comment: I wonder why you are using this method in the first place. When you need the "local" coordinates in some `JPanel`, why are you using `getLocationOnScreen` and not just `getPoint()`?

Comment: *"The entire code can be posted or e-mailed if needed."*  No thanks.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example) to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

if all you need is the position of the mouse cursor inside your own JFrame, there's no need to translate the coordinates given to you by `getLocationOnScreen()`.  [java.awt.MouseInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/MouseInfo.html) should help you get what you want:

```
Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
double x = p.getX();
double y = p.getY();
```

Comment: Will this go through the JPanel if clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`SwingUtilities`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) which provides a number of helper methods for converting between coordinate spaces

- [`convertMouseEvent(Component, MouseEvent, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertMouseEvent%28java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.event.MouseEvent,%20java.awt.Component%29)
- [`convertPoint(Component, int, int, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component%29)
- [`convertPoint(Component, Point, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint%28java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Component%29)
- [`convertPointFromScreen(Point, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29)
- [`convertPointToScreen(Point, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointToScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29)